# Efficiently Comparing Checking Maps inside a list of Objects in Java

Tags: java, memory, collections, hashmap

So, I have an object, that has a hashmap inside it (of course, with the corresponding getter and setter).

```
public class ObjA {
   private HashMap<String, Boolean> mymap;
   ...
}
```

Then, I have another class with a list of those objects (and corresponding getters/setters):

```
public class ObjB {
   private List<ObjA> list;
   ...
}
```

Then, a third class  `CheckerClass` needs to check how many `ObjA` in the list inside `ObjB` have the same map (this means same keys and same values for each key).

My initial thought was: loop the `list`, and for each `ObjA` parse its map to a `String`. Collect all the parsings on a `Collection`, and then count duplicates. But I want something more memory efficient, and more elegant: you know, easily read. And I'm not sure how to get it.

Comment: (1) Just declare `Map`, not `HashMap`, especially if you're wanting to do lots of retrievals (`TreeMap`) might be better. (2) There's a better name for `Map<T, Boolean>`: `Set<T>`.

Comment: @chrylis why do you think that a `TreeMap` might perform better than `HashMap` with lots of retrievals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way of creating a count of each unique map:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjA::getMyMap, Collectors.counting());
```

This works because `Map.equals` does exactly what you want: checks if the keysets are the same and map to equal values.

So then for each unique map you can find the number of times it appears in the list. Or if you specifically want to know how many duplicates there are, then use `.values().stream().filter(c -> c > 1).count()` on the resulting map.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is to modify `ObjA` as a Comparable object. You may do like this:

```
public class ObjA implements Comparable<ObjA>{
   private HashMap<String, Boolean> mymap;
   ...
  @Override
  public int compareTo(ObjA o) {
   //overide it by comparing key and value.
  }
}
```

In the `CheckerClass`. You can sort the ObjA list and count duplicated objects.

`Collections.sort(list)`